# Border radius and table borders - border sticks out on right side

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to make a table with rounded corners on all 4 sides.  I've been mostly successful, except in order for the radius property to work, I must remove the `table` border property.

This leaves the `td` border sticking out of the right hand side.  What I want to accomplish is to create a smooth even border on both the right and left side with a width of somewhere between 1-5 pixels.

I have tried a `border-box` `div` outside my `table`, but I couldn't seem to get that to work either.  Here is what I have.  Note the right border sticks out 1px:

```
<html>
<style>
    table { 
        border-collapse: collapse;
        max-width: 560;
    }
    
    th.top_curved{ 
        border-top-right-radius: 20px;
        border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    }

    th.bottom_curved{ 
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    }

    th{
        background-color: purple;
        color: white;
    }

    td{
        border: 1px solid purple;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 80px;">
            <col style="width: 80px;">
            <col style="width: 80px;">
            <col style="width: 80px">
            <col style="width: 80px">
            <col style="width: 80px">
            <col style="width: 80px">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <th class="top_curved" colspan="7">
                HEADER ROW
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="sub_header">Course</th>
            <th class="sub_header">Assignment</th>
            <th class="sub_header">Assigned</th>
            <th class="sub_header">Due</th>
            <th class="sub_header">Status</th>
            <th class="sub_header">Grade</th>
            <th class="sub_header">Comments</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th class="bottom_curved" colspan="7">
            HEADER ROW
        </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o018wpvx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.

Answer is to turn off the border-collapse property and turn border spacing to 0:

```
table { 
    border-spacing: 0;
    max-width: 560;
}
```